# What are the difference between these two closure syntax?

Tags: javascript, closures

I often use the closure syntax

```
var something = (function () {
  //TODO: do something 
}());
```

and, I often find people use this syntax

```
var something = (function () {
  //TODO: do something
})();
```

If both the two behaves the same way, what are the differences between the two?

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you should mention the duplicate link in the comment @RGraham

Comment: The link to the duplicate is now at the top of your question. Just under *This question already has an answer here*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real difference. Both statements contain function expressions that evaluate to functions that are immediately executed.